# Scrapy Can't POST with binary body using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

#### Description

My code was working in Python 2, but Scrapy is ending their support to Python 2 soon. I am trying to migrate to Python 3 but it seems Scrapy have some compatibility issues with binary in POST request.

#### Steps to Reproduce

I am trying to do this request with `reponse.body` populated with an image binary.

```
        yield scrapy.Request(u"{}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/prebuilt/receipt/asyncBatchAnalyze".format(self.endpoint), 
            method='POST',
            body=response.body,
            headers=self.binary_headers,
            callback=self.parse_result_url)
```

But then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<my_project>\receipts\receipts\receipts\spiders\receipt_recognizer.py", line 63, in parse_result_url
    yield scrapy.Request(response.headers['Operation-Location'], headers=self.receipt_headers, callback=self.parse_result)
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "c:\python374\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 63, in _set_url
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got bytes:
```

#### Versions

```
Scrapy       : 1.7.3
lxml         : 4.4.1.0
libxml2      : 2.9.5
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.5.2
w3lib        : 1.21.0
Twisted      : 19.7.0
Python       : 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
pyOpenSSL    : 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019)
cryptography : 2.7
Platform     : Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is on this part `yield scrapy.Request(response.headers['Operation-Location'], headers=self.receipt_headers, callback=self.parse_result)`

`response.headers['Operation-Location']` was in bytes. I should decode it first.

```
    url = response.headers['Operation-Location'].decode("utf-8")
    yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=self.receipt_headers, callback=self.parse_result)
```